# extJS Combobox autocomplete not working

Tags: extjs, combobox

I have a custom combobox and the autocomplete is not working. It is always displaying all results from the store

```
Ext.define('PMTool.view.calendar.ComboBox', {
        extend: 'Ext.form.ComboBox',
        alias: 'widget.calendar.combobox',
        store: 'Projects',
        queryMode: 'local',
        tpl: Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate',
        '<tpl for=".">',
            '<div class="x-boundlist-item">',
                                '<font color={projectColor}>{projectInitials}</font> {projectName}',
                        '</div>',
        '</tpl>'
    ),
        displayTpl: Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate',
                '<tpl  if="projectInitials.length != 0" for=".">',
                        '{projectInitials} {projectName}',
                '</tpl>',
                '<tpl else for=".">',
                        '',
                '</tpl>'
        )
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even with custom templates, you still need the `displayField` for the combo queries to work. You'll probably also want to set the `valueField`:

```
Ext.define('PMTool.view.calendar.ComboBox', {
    // ...
    displayField: 'projectName',
    valueField: 'id'
});
```